# Awk multiple pattern matching

Tags: awk

I want to skip first and last lines of file. And in the remaining records if length of record is greater than 300 and the third character should be k or m. Is there any to combine these validation together

To skip

```
awk 'NR>2{print v}{v=$0}' txtfile
```

For length

```
awk 'length($0) > 300'
```

For 3 character

```
awk '{print substr($0,3,1))}'
```

Anyway that I can put all these together
Thanks .

Comment: Sudhma nagabandi, Welcome to SO kindly wrap your code into CODE TAGS button in your post, also show us samples of input and expected output too in your post.

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output and then we can help you. Obviously do not use 300 as your line length.

Answer (score 0):

This awk one-liner will take 2nd line till the `last-1` line and do your `m/k` matching:

```
awk 'NR>1&&/^..[mk]/&&length($0)>300{if(NR>2)print p; p=$0}' file
```

Comment: But if file has around 3 matching records..the above awk is giving only first matching record

Comment: @sushmanagabandi I don't understand your comment. pls paste input exmaple and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

First some sample data that wasn't provided in the OP:

```
$ cat file
first
print
nok
nom
sixsix
last
```

Comparing against `length()<6`, replace with 300 or so:

```
$ awk 'b!~/^..[km]/&&length(b)<6&&NR>2{print b}{b=$0}' file
print
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
b !~ /^..[km]/ && length(b)<6 && NR>2 { print b } # analyze and print b, the buffer
{ b=$0 }' file                                    # buffer record for next iteration
```

- `NR>2` handles the first record
- lack of `END{}` and printing buffer `b` deals with the last record
- `b !~ /^..[km]/` 3rd char is k or m
- `length(b)<6` deal with the length of buffer

Comment: Thanks..it is dealing everything. But this is giving only first record which satisfies conditions. How can I all records?

Comment: Post some sample data and let me test. If I add those `print` records to `foo` the script outputs them all.

Answer (score 0):

Following will handle in case your Input_file is having capital letters eg-->`K` OR `M` in your Input_file too, since I am converting line to lower and comparing so it should catch those too.

```
awk 'prev{print prev;prev=""} FNR>1 && (substr(tolower($0),3,1)=="m" || substr(tolower($0),3,1)=="k") && length($0)>300{prev=$0} '  Input_file
```

***Explanation of code:***

```
awk '
prev                                                                                     {##Checking condition here if variable prev is NOT NULL then do following.
  print prev;                                                                             ##Printing the value of variable prev here.
  prev=""}                                                                                ##Making variable prev value as NULL here.
FNR>1 && (substr(tolower($0),3,1)=="m" || substr(tolower($0),3,1)=="k") && length($0)>300{##Checking conditions 1st- Making sure line number is greater than 1. 2nd- checking if 3rd character of current line is either m or k then 3rd condition if line length is greater than 300, if ALL conditions are TRUE then do following.
  prev=$0}                                                                                ##Setting variable prev value to current line then.
'  Input_file                                                                             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: @EdMorton, apologies Ed sir I didn't get it, since I am checking length there will it fail then too? could you please do let me know on same, will be grateful to you.

Comment: My apologies, I assumed you were doing one thing but you're actually doing something else. It's hard to read with those long horizontal scroll bars.